# How can I get specific paragraph where the keyword is(ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi I'm new in using elasticsearch, and I have a question about finding a keyword in a content.

In case of Es, when I search a specific keyword, the ES shows the whole content where the keyword is in.

But I want to find some strings before, and ahead of a specific keyword, such as

keyword: "banana"

content: "I like banana because it's tasty"

how can I get this data?

keyword: "banana"

content: "I like banana because it's tasty"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html) and the `fragment_size`.

fragment_size: The size of the highlighted fragment in characters. Defaults to 100.

> When used with the unified highlighter, the sentence scanner splits
> sentences bigger than fragment_size at the first word boundary next to
> fragment_size. You can set fragment_size to 0 to never split any
> sentence.

```
PUT test_banana/_doc/1
{
  "content": "I like banana because it's tasty"
}

GET test_banana/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "banana"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 1,
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, i was wondering if i can adjust some characters i want to see before, and ahead of such keyword?

for exapmle, "banana' -> "like banana because"

Comment: you're welcome, please check the highlight documentation that I shared above. AFAIR not the after but you can adjust the before with `fragment_Size`.